# Why Device Manager don't open?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm working on the Flutter project. After I updated the version of the Android Studio when I click on the device manager to open my devices it doesn't show. I don't know what should I do?

At the first image it's gif image to explain what I mean.

[image]

I put the second image to show current version (Bumblebee).

[image]

Comment: So, your project doesn't have ANDROID module...

Answer (score 142, accepted):

IntelliJ (Android Studio) wants to know what kind of project you have to show the right menus.

1. click left in file tree on the root node (project name)
2. MENU -> FILE -> PROJECT STRUCTURE
3. select left MODULES
4. hit + button to add ANDROID
5. hit OK Button
6. top of the root node (project name) select PROJECT... to see your old view

Comment: This may be useful: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5917

Answer (score 106):

press shift 2 times to open search everything and type "Virtual Device Manager".

Comment: This trick works, but I'm curious still why it doesn't work straight from the menu bar?

Answer (score 19):

I also face this issue with new Update of Android studio. So i just got a solution..

Go to the `Search icon` on the top of Right Corner or `Press Shift Button twice` to open a Search window.
And Search `Virtual Device Manager` then you will eaisly got your Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue - pressing device manger from "Tools > Device Manager" is doing nothing. However the device manger is located on the left side bar and works just fine

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Android studio no android module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVd86.png)

Please check whether your flutter project is creating Android module by clicking left side of the android studio.
Also try another SDK location or try renaming it.
Do not delete the previous sdk since it seems it creates some issue while opening the device manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem related to the button that opens the device manager because it opens when you search with "Virtual Device Manager".