# AVD manager is not responding in Androd Studio BumbleBee 2021.1.1 for flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, avd-manager

AVD manager icon is not responding. I opened a native app project and the icon is responding. But it doesn't respond if I click it from a flutter project. Tried restarting, reinstalling.

Comment: Here is a Solution for your problem (duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864465/why-device-manager-dont-open/70864830#70864830

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Double press the SHIFT key on your keyboard and search for "virtual device manager" and it will open for you as usual.

Answer (score 0):

if you are opening a Flutter project, open any android native project in another window and it will work well, it will be fixed in future updates

Comment: Can you share a link to a bug report?  You say this this will be fixed in future updates.  How do you know?  How can the post author know?