# Device manager does not work (open) after updating Android Studio to 2021.1.1

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

Android studio's device manager AVD manager works fine in old versions, but in 2021.1.1 version does not open!
Windows 10 and 11 tested
last version flutter
Intel
Sdk manager everything updated
could anyone help?

Comment: 'does not open' means stuck or blank screen or anything else?

Comment: I mean when I Click on the device manager icon, it does not work or open anything

Comment: Delete and recreate, device manager works well in my pc and the android studio is 2021.1.1.

Comment: I tested this version even in windows 10 and windows 11, both of them does not work :|

Comment: I have the same problem, after update to version 2021.1.1 the device emulator appear to be running, but is is not opened, also adb.exe is loaded

Comment: I have downgraded to version 2020.3.1 and emulator works normally.

Comment: I have tried both on  MacOSX 15.2.1 and Ubuntu 22.04 and I get the same problem, it won't open.

Comment: You should press shift 2 times to open search everything and type "Virtual Device Manager". This way you can open it

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864465/why-device-manager-dont-open/70866555

Answer (score 28):

I still have the same problem with the Bumblebee version, but for now you can use the `Search Everywhere` feature (you can access "Search Everywhere" by pressing double `shift`) and type in

"Virtual Device Manager"

then it will works.
This is a temporary solution for now.

Answer (score 12):

Step 1: Select **FILE** (on the top left)
Step 2: Select **PROJECT STRUCTURE** (<**Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S**> on Windows/Linux).
Step 3: Select **MODULES** on the left under Project Settings.
Step 4: Hit the plus (+) button.
Step 5: Add **ANDROID** and hit **OK** Button.

Now you can open Device Manager

Comment: Thank you loads, you saved my day.
Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1
macOS Monterey 12.0.1 (Apple M1)

Comment: Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1 Windows 10 Professional verified, for flutter project

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, found the solution to return the icon to the toolbar, where it's easy to use it.

I guess it happans to anyone who upgrades from prvious version.

**The idea is just to replace the "old" device manager with the new device manager created in 2021.1.1.**

1. Right click the right side of the top toolbar and click the "Customize Menues and toolbars.
2. In the "Menus and Toolbar" window expand "Main Toolbar"
3. Expand "Android.MainToolBarActionGroup"
4. Press the "+" button in the top and select "Add Action..."
5. In the "Choose Action To Add" windows , search for "Virtual Device manager", select it and press OK.
6. You will see the the new icon is added.

To make sure it's working you can press OK to close this window and return to Android Studio main screen.

**Now, you should have 2 similar icons in the toolbar, only the bubbles will be different.**

- The old is called "Device manager"
- The new one is called "Virtual Device Manager"

Make sure it really works and opens the new Device Manager.

**Once it is working , you can go back to the toolbar manger and delete the old icon.**

Folow setps 1-3 above

4. Locate the "Android.RunAndroidAvdManager" item, select it and delete it by pressing the "-" button in the top of the screen.
5. Close this window and return to main screen.

[image: The old and new device managers in Android Studio]

Comment: As stated in the other answer below, I also had to add the item to the "Navigation Bar Toolbar" instead of the "Main Toolbar" https://stackoverflow.com/a/71206640/6607383

Answer (score 1):

I too met this problem temp solution this that which wrote [Zaid Salam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18146099/zaid-salam)

My version Android Studio -> Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 1
My OS -> macOS Monterey

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot seem to be able to right-click the toolbar as Yahalom mentioned, go to View > Appearance and select Toolbar.

The toolbar will move and a big space will be available on the right to right-click.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71040952/2096733), the update from an older version does not replace the button action correctly.

But to fix it for me (Android Studio on Linux), I had to edit the **Navigation Bar Toolbar** rather than the **Main Toolbar**. As the [IntelliJ docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/guided-tour-around-the-user-interface.html#navigation-bar) mention, the main toolbar is hidden by default.

(Could not comment on the original answer yet, so I had to create a separate response)